# Verify Image data from tfrecord files using tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, computer-vision

I am new to tensorflow and I am trying to verify my custom dataset tfrecord data by extracting images as tensor and convert to np array and display them as jpegs.

But it seems to be hung forever at this step >>> sess.run(image_tensor)

My code looks like this:-

```
dataset = Dataset.Dataset("Imagenet","train")
print('starting data_files scan....')
assert dataset.data_files()
print('done data_files scan....')
print('FLAGS.num_preprocess_threads >> ',FLAGS.num_preprocess_threads)

images, labels = distorted_inputs(dataset,num_preprocess_threads=FLAGS.num_preprocess_threads)
print('labels >>>',labels) # Tensor("batch_processing/Reshape_1:0", shape=(1,), dtype=int32, device=/device:CPU:0)
print('images >> ', images) # Tensor("batch_processing/Reshape:0", shape=(1, 199, 199, 3), dtype=float32, device=/device:CPU:0)
reshaped_img = tf.reshape(images,[199,199,3])
#tmp_var = tf.Variable(reshaped_img)
print('new >>> ',reshaped_img.shape)#199,199,3 
with tf.Session() as sess:
    init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(init_op)
    example, l = sess.run([reshaped_img, label])# its hung at this step forever no error
    img = PIL.Image.fromarray(example, 'RGB')
    img.save( "output/" + str(i) + '-train.png')
    # OR >>> PIL.Image.fromarray(np.asarray(x)).show()
```

**its hung at this step forever no error**:--

```
example, l = sess.run([reshaped_img, label])
```

Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's likely that queues gets started somewhere, and without a QueueRunner graph execution blocks indefinitely waiting for something to be enqueued. You could either [start a QueueRunner manually](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/reading_data#creating_threads_to_prefetch_using_queuerunner_objects), or switch over to using a `tf.contrib.learn.Estimator` which handles this and other initializations for you.

Comment: @AllenLavoie Thanks for pointing in right direction that helped. Now I am able to plot an image but next issue is image is just a random color pattern n not what I have bundled in tfrecord files. Is there anything elementary concept you can point me to regarding dequeue ? Basically I want to feed data into my custom convNet in batches/ stream so that I can fee more data into validation+test runs.

Comment: To read a batch of data from a queue, you can `dequeue_many`. Often resizing and such is done on single images and in parallel, and those results are added to a queue and read out in batches for training. Not sure why the images aren't coming out; if you can come up with a minimal example it might make sense to put that in a new question.